# Bigquery : get the name of the table as column value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset that contains several tables that have suffixes in their name:

- table_src1_serie1
- table_src1_serie2
- table_src2_opt1
- table_src2_opt2
- table_src3_type1_v1
- table_src3_type2_v1
- table_src3_type2_v2

I know that i can use this type of queries in BQ:

```
select * from `project.dataset.table_*`
```

to get all the rows from theses different tables.

What i am trying to achieve is to have a column that will contain for instance the type of source (src1, src2, src3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the schema of all tables the same - you can add below to your select list (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SPLIT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS src
```

Comment: sure, you can use `As Source`